# How to create a mailitem?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to send the active Excel workbook as an attachment via Outlook.

Whenever I run the code it says

> Invalid use of New key word

at New Outlook.MailItem`.

```
Sub SendOutlook()
    'Declaring Variables
    Dim OutlookApp  As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookEmail  As Outlook.MailItem

    'Assigning variables to create outlook application and mailitem
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookEmail = New Outlook.MailItem
    
    With OutlookEmail
        'Format of the mail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        'Body of the mail
        .Body = "Dear Someone" & vbNewLine & "How are you?"
        'To whom you want to send mail
        .To = "Someone@somewhere.com"
        'Subject of mail
        .Subject = "Write Subject Here"
        'TO add an attachment
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'sends the mail
        .Send
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Im getting an error near 'New.Outlook.MailItem'

Comment: You should use `Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.MailItem`.

Comment: After setting it up as Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.MailItem it says user defined type not defined @shrivallabha.redij

Comment: It means you have not set library references for the objects being used in the code. Please check `Tools >> References` and see if you have set relevant references such as `outlook object library`

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I had included Microsoft outlook 16.0 object library

Comment: Is `outlook` the only external object that you are using in your code?

Comment: Yes @shrivallabha.redij you can see the code above.

Comment: Is this whole code that we are dealing with? Declaring variables with explicit object is one part and setting library references another (checking them in Tools >> References).

Comment: Yes this is the whole code I have posted here @shrivallabha.redij

Comment: OK then please change line `Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)` and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Previously: https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/unexpected-invalid-use-of-new-keyword.252478/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a `MailItem` via `New`. It must be created using `CreateItem` of the the Outlook Application Object.

```
   Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
   Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a programmatic approach with the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private outlook_app As Object
Private outlook_mailItem As Variant

Sub send_email()

    Set outlook_app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    With outlook_app.CreateItem(outlook_mailItem)
        .To = "Someone@somewhere.com"
        .Subject = "Write Subject Here"
        .Body = "Dear Someone" & vbNewLine & "How are you?"
        .send
    End With
    Set outlook_app = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I got to know from the research is that Programmatic access to sending emails is a security risk, so it's not allowed via VBA.

Comment: I don't know about that... I've created applications before in both word and excel that send 'auto emails' without the user even seeing outlook (e.g. if an error occurs or once something is submitted etc.).

Comment: @Samuel Everson So can you share the code for outlook as well as the tool references you add ? It would be of great help

Comment: @SiddhantSingh - there are *tons* of posts (with answers) here on SO which cover what you want to do.

Comment: I don't have the code any more (made for an ex employer). But, what Tim said.