# (Excel VBA) Outlook Application CreateItem Fails in Certain Situation

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

In our company .xlsm, I'm using "standard" macro to send e-mails via Outlook:

```
Dim olApp As Object, olMail As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If olApp Is Nothing Then
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

With olMail
    'properties, methods, events
End With
```

The thing is, it works on all company computers except for one. On this one:

- If Outlook client is closed when running macro, everything works fine;
- If Outlook client is opened when running macro, it returns Error '91' (Object variable not set) on Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0).

What could be the cause?

Comment: Not the standard. Move `On Error GoTo 0` above `If olApp is Nothing Then`.

Comment: Outlook does not create a new instance so the `GetObject()` is pointless - you may as well call `CreateObject()` directly.

Comment: @niton Alright, this was a logical move I should've considered. Now I'm getting error '-2146959355 (80080005)' - Server execution failed on line `Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`, which is equal to Nothing in debug mode. So it didn't grab the opened Outlook app and failed creating one. Still no idea why's that happening, but thanks for pushing me further.

Comment: As indicated by KostasK. `GetObject()` is not necessary for Outlook. A new object will be the same Outlook. While waiting for an explanation of the behaviour you describe, here are two possible workarounds. `Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application` https://stackoverflow.com/a/53247312/1571407 or `Set olApp = New Outlook.Application` https://stackoverflow.com/a/62082770/1571407.

Answer (score 0):

Your Excel Application must be run under the same security context with Outlook running to be able to get the running instance.

> If Outlook client is opened when running macro, it returns Error '91' (Object variable not set) on Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0).

If you run Excel with admin privileges you need to run Outlook as well with admin privileges to be able to connect them together.

Also you may try to use the early-binding technology instead of late-binding one. For that you need to add an Outlook COM reference in the Excel COM References dialog (see the VBA editor). Read more about that in the [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients) article.